# Charge conjugation Operator for non-abelian group of a fermion

Tags: quantum-field-theory, yang-mills, charge-conjugation

For deriving the Charge conjugation operator one (the Schwartz book) takes the complex conjugate of the Dirac equation like the following, where $\psi_c=C\psi^*$:

$$(i\partial_\mu \gamma^\mu-eA_\mu\gamma^\mu-m)\psi=0$$
$$(-i\partial_\mu (\gamma^\mu)^*-eA_\mu(\gamma^\mu)^*-m)\psi^*=0$$
$$(-i\partial_\mu (\gamma^\mu)^*-eA_\mu(\gamma^\mu)^*-m)C^{-1}C\psi^*=0$$
$$(-i\partial_\mu (\gamma^\mu)^*-eA_\mu(\gamma^\mu)^*-m)C^{-1}\psi_c=0$$
$$C^{-1}(i\partial_\mu \gamma^\mu+eA_\mu\gamma^\mu-m)\psi_c=0$$
$$(i\partial_\mu \gamma^\mu+eA_\mu\gamma^\mu-m)\psi_c=0$$
$$\Rightarrow C(\gamma^\mu)^*C^{-1}\overset{!}{=}-\gamma^\mu$$
For general $SU(N)$ fermions in the fundamental representation (generators $T^a$) we have the following Dirac equation
$$(i\partial_\mu \gamma^\mu-gA_\mu^a T^a\gamma^\mu-m)\psi=0$$
$$(-i\partial_\mu (\gamma^\mu)^*-gA_\mu^a (T^a\gamma^\mu)^*-m)\psi^*=0$$
$$(-i\partial_\mu (\gamma^\mu)^*-gA_\mu^a(T^a\gamma^\mu)^*-m)C^{-1}C\psi^*=0$$
$$(-i\partial_\mu (\gamma^\mu)^*-gA_\mu^a(T^a)^*(\gamma^\mu)^*-m)C^{-1}\psi_c=0$$
$$C^{-1}(i\partial_\mu \gamma^\mu+gA_\mu^aC(T^a)^*C^{-1}\gamma^\mu-m)\psi_c=0$$
$$(i\partial_\mu \gamma^\mu-gA_\mu^aT^a_\text{anti}\gamma^\mu-m)\psi_c=0$$
$$\Rightarrow T^a_\text{anti}=-C(T^a)^*C^{-1}$$
Now I know that the antifundamental representation should be in general $T^a_\text{anti}=-(T^a)^*$, but can we be sure of this that the $C$ matrix is trivial in the internal space of the gauge group?

Comment: The $C$ matrix acts only on the spin indices, not on the group indices.  BTW I think  it better to use transposition rather than complex conjugation: Define it by $C^{-1}\gamma^\mu C=-(\gamma^\mu)^T$ as this is independent of the signature and/or sign convention for the metric.

Comment: @mikestone Yes but I was wondering if there is any reason why the $C$ matrix has to be trivial in the internal space.

Comment: It's just that it does not *need* to do anything to the internal space.  As you have noted the $T^a$ matrices commute with the $\gamma^\mu$ in the same way. My own understanding of this starts from Hitoshi Murayama lectures at http://hitoshi.berkeley.edu/230A/clifford.pdf and I strongly recommend them.